# Files are not downloading in the specifed download directory in chrome-headless and selenium java

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

During the test, a file(.pdf) will be downloaded from the web application and i have to verify whether the file is downloaded or not under a specific path. But whenever I'm going to headless mode, the file is not getting downloaded to the download path (i.e. pointed in the "download.default_directory"). Instead it is getting downloaded to the "user.dir"('/home/<>/git/bb-cloud/<>).
Chrome version : 110.0.5481.100 ; OS : Ubuntu 20.04
Below is my code which is used to invoke chrome-headless,

```
public WebDriver createInstance(String browser) {
WebDriver driverInstance = null;
try {
  if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome-headless")) {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    HashMap < String, Object > hashmap = new HashMap < > ();
    hashmap.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    hashmap.put("download.prompt_for_download", "false");
    hashmap.put("download.default_directory", '/home/<<USER>>/git/bb-cloud/<<PROJECT>>/src/main/resources');
    hashmap.put("browser.set_download_behavior", "{ behavior: 'allow' , downloadPath: '/home/<<USER>>/git/bb-cloud/<<PROJECT>>/src/main/resources'}");

    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", hashmap);

    options.addArguments("start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");

    options.addArguments("headless");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--allow-insecure-localhost");

    options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
    driverInstance = new ChromeDriver(options);
  }
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return driverInstance;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the "headless" option to "--headless=new"

This recently changed in Chrome 109

https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/

Comment: I tried, it is not working. What else, other than `--headless=new` do I need in order to enable downloads? None of the two articles you linked to mentions any of it. How can this be the accepted answer?

Comment: @kriegaex you have to apply its ```options.addArguments("--headless=new")```

Comment: That has no effect whatsoever. Maybe this is because I use Selenium 3 in that legacy project. The latest Chrome driver is no problem, but upgrading all testing tools and build configs to Selenium 4 would be a major effort. I thought that the options are passed on to the driver, so Selenium version should not be important. Can anyone enlighten me?